# Breadcrumb positioning in OpenCart

Tags: html, css, position, opencart

I want to move breadcrumb to the header section, but I found that it's nearly impossible. I tried absolute positioning, but the breadcrumb moves with page resize. I ran out of ideas.

Is there any way to move breadcrumb to the header, with css/or any other way?

[Here](http://goo.gl/nkJgsG) is my demo site, try resize the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move breadcrump to the right position which is inside div with class: "breadcrumbd" under the header. But if you don't want to change your html mark up you can achieve this with the following changes:

```
#column-left + #column-right + #content, #column-left + #content {
  margin-left: 180px;
  position: relative; /* Add position: relative to content*/
}
```

remove `overflow: hidden;` from #container

```
.breadcrumb {
  left: -182px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -49px;
}
```

But I really not reccoment such an absolute solution. reconsider to change your markup.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to move breadcrumb to the header section (breadcrumbd). Too many modification required to make it work (core changes). Thanks I'll try this css hack.